# Is there any other way to query / load local images in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview, android-image

I'm trying to display local images in grid view. And I want it to load faster. So instead of fetching images and load them at once, I want them to load by group.

So is there any other way to query/load local images in Android, aside from the code below?

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                       .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
                              mProjection, null, null, 
                              MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
Glide.with(imageView)
     .load(/*file.jpg/png, drawable, url*/)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)// you can remove this line
     .dontAnimate()
     .into(imageView);
```

in your gradle(Module: app) add this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. Yes, I am using Glide Library. But my concern is about the fetching or querying local images. Is there a way to fetch images with limited numbers when scrolling, instead of fetching all at once? For me to be able to load the images faster. Again thank you.

Comment: r u using ArrayAdapter?

Comment: if so you can load each image in the `getView` method,
see example here https://abhiandroid.com/ui/gridview